# AWS Elastic Beanstalk inserts folder in url

Tags: php, url, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a usual php/angular.js project, where my index.php file is in root / and the other files are in folders like /css or /bower-components and so on.

When I zip this and upload it to Elastic Beanstalk, I get a strange problem:
AWS finds my index.php file, but for all other files like .js and .css Elastic 
Beanstalk inserts an extra folder in the url.
I have absolutely no idea why.

Comment: Could you show us exactly what you mean by "inserts and extra folder in the url"?

Comment: I have e.g. <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"> and AWS makes it to <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://projectname.elasticbeanstalk.com/projectname/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">

Answer (score 0):

Chances are this is due to how you are zipping up your code.
But if you want to fix this without changing your zip all you need to do is tell Beanstalk what your "document root" is.

Using the Elastic Beanstalk web console:

```
Click on environment -> Configuration -> Software Configuration (Gear icon) -> Document Root. First option on page.
```

Set to: `projectname`